# Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I get an error (Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.) on the following code (`ContentType` line). What should I change?

```cs
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PervasiveConstants.DownloadZipLocation) + ";");
response.TransmitFile(PervasiveConstants.DownloadZipLocation);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

This is within a Sharepoint 2010 webpart.

Comment: This is the general "problem" for all servers. Once program starts generating content, headers should be sent to client and could not be changed.
In order to set headers anywhere in programm, you need to enable output buffering or somewhat. It is called "output buffering" in Apache/php, but there should be similar thing in another servers.

Comment: Why do you start with `ClearContent`? If the response already *has* content, then your code is probably running too late in the process.

Answer (score 7):

Try setting `response.BufferOutput = true;`. Do this immediately after setting the `response` variable.

Comment: I used 


**System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;**
**Response.BufferOutput = true;**


But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at HttpResponse.BufferOutput Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33cy25ty%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue to this on a webform. I solved this issue by adding the following code to my button in the code behind:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnPrint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* to set the content type?  This solution should not be overlooked, because you may find your code to work perfectly without the need to explicitly define the content type for the type of response you are sending.  So removing the following line should make the error go away, and may very well do so without introducing new problems (of course you'll want to test this against your scenario):

`response.ContentType = "text/plain";`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me,
add this line of code on the beginning of the method,

```
Server.ClearError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an error in any of the filters applied to the controller or action which causes response redirect or response header to be written before the actual request.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and the following solution solved the problem, 
run a `response.ClearHeaders();` before run `response.AddHeader(`