# Unable to create link to download file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to provide a link to download a zip file on an asp.net webpage but just can't get it working.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I have the following link

```
<a href="#" runat="server" ID="lnkDownload" 
Text="Download Zip" onServerClick="DownloadFile">Download TestFile</a>
```

and codebehind,

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    string DownloadPath = "/Members/Download/TestFile.zip";
    //string DownloadPath = "~/Members/Download/TestFile.zip";
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
          "attachment; filename=\"" + "TestFile.zip" + "\"");
    Response.Clear();
    Response.WriteFile(DownloadPath);
    Response.End();
}
```

The code runs when the link is clicked but nothing downloads and I then get an error on `Response.End();` which is

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: What real error you got. `A first chance exception` usually is not important. The "real" example gives you a clue

Comment: The details says "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."

Comment: What other exception you got? Maybe add in your code try and catch to get details of the exception which you are interested in.

Comment: That is the only error, even when catching the Exception. Also, the method DownloadFile is in a control .ascx if that makes a difference?

Comment: Where in your cose is try-catch? You probably set to catch all thrown exceptions in Visual Studio. This option cacthes much more exceptions which normally aren't important. Look here to see what is first chance exception: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DownloadPath);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.TransmitFile(DownloadPath);
Response.Flush();
```

--- Updated code

```
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(DownloadPath);

            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.BufferOutput = true;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());

                Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                Response.Flush();


            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("File not found");
            }
```

Comment: I no longer get any errors using this code, the code runs but there is no save file dialog?

Comment: Is it something related to postback as TransmitFile is just not firing?

Comment: It definitely exists and `FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(DownloadPath);` reports Exists==true;

Comment: If I enable break on all exceptions I get the following error "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360857/server-cannot-set-content-type-after-http-headers-have-been-sent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47178/discussion-between-irfan-tahirkheli-and-ooo)